# Moving a table to a different tablespace in Oracle using Online Redefinition Vs Alter table move tablespace

Tags: oracle, alter-table, dbms-redefinition

I have a table with 1 Billion records with size 300GB to move to different tablespace.
My question here is - What is the advantage of using DBMS_REDEFINITION (Online redefinition) package
over Alter table  move ;
Which one is fast and why?
Can we have DML access to table in either ways of moving the table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Those two methods are very different.

```
Alter table mytable move mytablespace
```

will move all the data blocks into the new tablespace. while it doing so, **the table will be locked for DML.**

DBMS_REDEFINITION will allow you to create a new table on the desired tablespace and sync the data between them **ONLINE**. when the sync ends the tables names will be switched.
you will have to be careful with DBMS_REDEFINITION as you have to create the new table youself including indexes, constraints, partition, privs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not important to keep a table available for DML when moving it to another tablespace, you can use the simpler ALTER TABLE MOVE command

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#ADMIN11667